# Odd behaviour of dropdown in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am making hybrid app using Angular JS, wherein there is an page which has two dropdown (select controls).

The thing should be,When I select the first dropdown the second one automatically should fill based on the data fetched on change of first doropdown; but what happens is on change of first dropdown the data is fetched but it is not getting bind to second dropdown immediately though the model of second dropdown gets the data fetched on selection of first dropdown, instead what happens is when i again change the first dropdown selection, the previous data gets bind to the second dropdown.

Below is my code for the same - 
Car Make dropdown -

```
 <select name="make" 
                    ng-options="item.MakeId as item.Make for item in memberdetailData.VehicleData" 
                    ng-model="memberdetailData.selected_Make_ID" 
                    ng-change="vehiclemakeselected()">
```

Car Model Dropdown -

```
<select name="model"  ng-disabled="memberdetailData.selected_Make_ID === {}" 
                    ng-options="item.ModelId as item.Model for item in memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model" 
                    ng-model="memberdetailData.selected_Model"></select>
```

Controller code -

```
  $scope.vehiclemakeselected = function () {


    console.log($scope.memberdetailData.selected_Make_ID);
    //console.log($scope.memberdetailData.selected_Make_ID);
    db_factory.selectVehicleMasterData('select ModelId,Model from tbl_vehicle WHERE MakeId ="' + $scope.memberdetailData.selected_Make_ID + '";', function (res) {


        console.log("this is respo");
        //console.log(res);
        $scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model = null;
        $scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model = res;
        console.log($scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model);
        //            console.log($scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model);
        $scope.memberdetailData.selected_Model = null;
        $scope.memberdetailData.selected_Model = $scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model[0].ModelId;



    }, function () {
        //            globalFactory.showAlert('Data Error', 'No Salutation Master Found, Kindly Sync Salutation Master');
    });

}
```

DBFactory -

```
db_factory_obj.selectVehicleMasterData = function (query, callBack, errorcall) {

    var result = [];
    db_factory_obj.db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, rs) {

            for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                result[i] = {
                    MakeId: row['MakeId'],
                    Make: row['Make'],
                    ModelId: row['ModelId'],
                    Model: row['Model']
                }
            }

            ////console.log(result);
            callBack(result); // <-- new bit here
        }, errorcall);
    });


}
```

Please help.

Thanks.
Krunal

Comment: oh!! sorry, have edited my question with controller code.

Comment: added db_factory_obj.selectVehicleMasterData - edited question

Comment: tried, not working.. added this in controller
 setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model = null;
                $scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model = res;
                console.log($scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model);
                $scope.memberdetailData.selected_Model = null;
                $scope.memberdetailData.selected_Model = $scope.memberdetailData.Vehicle_Model[0].ModelId;
            }, 0);

Comment: mate `$timeout` not `setTimeout` or `$timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(); //this triggers a $digest
    }, 1);`

Comment: awesome one...it worked thanks :)